# Send email from a website using the webhosting server

Tags: javascript, email, server, web-hosting

I'm currently doing a website for someone and I want to add a form to Contact Us page to send a message to their email address using the webhosting server they have without Php.
Can anyone help me with this I can't wrap my head around the process and how to make it secure and actually make it work. Do I have to deploy something on the server or can I use the smpt server they have there and if so how can I make sure the smtp server auth not visible on devtools from the client side.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

For a project like this, I used https://www.smtpjs.com/ to send email using smtp directly by frontend javascript.

To secure the email account's password, they generate a token (a secret key). It is very easy to setup. Just follow the instructions on their homepage and you are good to go.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but with this way they going to have the smtp credentials on their server. Any other way?

Comment: smtp credentials are not exposed to public. secureToken is used for this purpose.

Comment: Another solution would be complex. You can create a simple node app and host it on Heroku. Then, you can use Sendgrid API to send email. Their free plan should be sufficient for most cases.

Comment: Happy to help :) If this answer, or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.